# Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction error?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am facing this error on build for the function shown in the code

> Only instance methods can be declared @IBAction

this error is coming up only after I introduced google sign in method for similar functionality , earlier it not an error

```
   @IBAction func SignInButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let email = emailField.text else { return }
        guard let pass = passwordField.text else { return }


        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass) { user, error in
            if error == nil && user != nil {

                let setupcheckref = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)

                setupcheckref.getDocument{(document, error) in
                    if let document = document, document.exists{
                        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"

                        self.checksetup = document.get("setupComplete") as! Bool

                        if self.checksetup == true {
                            if Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified {
                                               self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLoginFeed", sender: self)
                                           }
                                           else{
                                               print("please verify your email")
                                               try! Auth.auth().signOut()



                                           }

                        }

                        else{

                            self.view.makeToast("Please Setup Your Account!", duration: 2.5)

                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromlogintosetup", sender: self)
                            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        } }

                }







                // self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

            } else {
                print("Error logging in: \(error!.localizedDescription)")

               // self.resetForm()
               // SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check whether your brackets are balanced.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks, bracket balance was the issue, resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you can create `@IBActions` only as *instance methods* of a class.

You might be creating it of a `class`.

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func SignInButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //your code...
    }
}
```